# does $ \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt[]{n})$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt[]{n})$ converge?
And if so to what value?

(Please dont share the Wolfram Alpha Solution. This is too abstract and not like a human would solve it!)

thanks 
Joe

Comment: Converge? When $n$ does whar?

Comment: goes to infinity

Comment: @BukkitDEV Use mathjax , add context , show attempt.

Comment: @Avenger is used it as you can see in the question. Please look first before posting such a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt n (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)
&\stackrel{(1)}= \sqrt n \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} \\
&= \frac1{\sqrt{1+1/n}+1} \\
\end{align}$$
where $(1)$ is an extension by some term that you can work out.

The result is simpler in the sense that it has only one occurence of $n$ and the nasty difference has gone; you should be able to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising!
But what extension do you use to multiply to get (1)

Comment: It uses binomial formula $a-b=(a^2-b^2)/(a+b)$ which is a standard approach because it simplifies to $a^2-b^2=1$ which eliminates the annoying difference.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply and divide by the conjugate to get $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$
To find limit of this you can factor out square root and some more rewriting to get the result (probably the way WA does).

Another approach is squeeze theorem. Compare to $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1+\sqrt{n}}$ to get the result.